# Ionic toast forces user to stop typing

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I'm building an app using Ionic, Angular Firebase.

I'm having a unique problem where if a user is typing into a textbox and a toast appears it hides the keyboard and forces the user to stop typing... Is there a way to prevent this?

The app is a social network so people get notifications quite often and the code is quite simple as well:

```
this.listenToNotifications().pipe(
    tap(msg => {
      let message = msg.body || "You have a new notification!";
      const toast = this.toastCtrl.create({
        message: message,
        duration: 3000,
        position: 'top',
        showCloseButton: true,
        closeButtonText: "Ok"
      });
      toast.present();
    })
  ).subscribe()
```

Anyone know of a solution?

Thank you :)

Comment: This is described in the docs, see here: https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/platform/Keyboard/

Comment: @DmitryStepanov What am I looking for? Are you suggesting when I listen to notifications and I notice the user is typing I should not show the notification?

Comment: Perhaps this may help you out? https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-plugin-keyboard/issues/81

Comment: @JaneDoe or show later